# Why would adding one more C++ class to linux shared lib cause exe to crash before main()?

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries, elf, segmentation-fault

I have a GNU C++ linux exe on RHEL 6.3 x86_64 which uses several shared lib's.  All Shared Lib are complied with -fPIC for position independent code.  I add one additional C++ class to a particular shared lib and my exe sigsegv's in __do_global_ctors_aux. The error produced is "global constructors keyed to scollection.cpp()".  This scollection.cpp is a class in another shared lib, not the one I just added the additional class in.

Neither the additional class or the scollection.cpp class has static items which is what __do_global_ctors_aux is supposed to be creating. When I compile the library with this additional class as a static lib, *.a, and link the exe runs with out a problem. Also note the exe crashing does not use this additional class. Also tried removing several classes in this shared lib, thinking I reached some limit, left the new class in, and still had the same crash.

Could the additional class have a symbol reference the same as some other class ?
Is the sigsegv in __do_global_ctors_aux a red-herring, or is there a real conflict between this additional class and the scollection.cpp? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does gdb say about the exact site/reason of the crash?

Comment: Adding the code that causes the issue would help us diagnose the problem.

Comment: Wild guess: Broken static initialization.